# Compare and merge two word documents using php

Tags: php

I am doing a project on online medical transcription training. For that we are not allowed the original documents to the users.

User must type all the contents he hear and he uploads the documents to the server. Then the Original document will be compared or merged to his edited document and the result file will be downloaded to him to verify.

I need to do this in php? is it possible?

I heard about COM object in php. but i dint find any good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred in link

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.text.text-diff.intro.php

It has the feature what i specified. It compare two documents and also has merge document.

Answer (score 0):

By searching "word com php", you should find a lot of sample code via Google.
However, there are other solutions (e.g. convert .doc to html or text) which should be faster and less platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that what word shows as content of a doc is not allways its complete content, but a result of more or less editing. Two docs may show amd print the very same text, but may contain just this plain text as well as large portions of deleted/edited/changed text and as such be much much bigger. So your only choice is IMHO to use calls to word to compare two or more different documents.